# Using jhipster upgrade stucks at command prompt for "May JHipster anonymously report"

Tags: java, upgrade, jhipster

I'm trying to upgrade jhipster to version 5.4.1 with `jhipster upgrade` on windows.

The process however stucks once the installation is done and the command `.bin/jhipster --with-entities --force --skip-install` is being executed.

The process stucks at the command prompt with following message:

```
? May JHipster anonymously report usage statistics to improve the tool over time
? (Y/n)
```

I'm unable to continue from there with the process as I'm unable to select any option. There is no reaction on my input from keyboard.

Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks and regards.

Comment: What version are you upgrading from?

Comment: For those finding this question, see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/8465#issuecomment-427280486

Answer (score 1):

Is a know issue and was fixed in newer versions. Original Issue:

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/8156

There is also a workaround mentioned there.